# Retrofitting old Python code

Tags: python, subprocess

I have the following piece of old python code.

```
cmd = '/usr/bin/passwd --stdin %s' % sys_user
(pin, pout) = os.popen2(cmd)
pin.write(password)
pin.close()
pout.read()
pout.close()
```

I did not write it. Original programmer long gone. Documentation is next to zip.
The open2 is deprecated.

So how do I manage to convert to using subprocess? I am not a python programmer, but can figure things out.

This bit of code does not work, but I am obviously missing something.

```
cmd = '/usr/bin/passwd --stdin %s' % sys_user
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.stdin.write(password)
proc.stdin.close()
proc.stdout.read()
proc.stdout.close()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

r

Comment: the code should work if you replace `cmd` by `shlex.split(cmd)`. If you don't use the output then just set it to `subprocess.DEVNULL` or `DEVNULL = open(os.devnull, 'wb', 0)` (you don't need to read the `proc.stdout` in this case) instead of PIPE.

Answer (score 0):

1. When working with `subprocess` your call can be a list: `cmd = ['/usr/bin/passwd', '--stdin', sys_user]`
2. You are missing the `proc.communicate()` step.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you'd better use a list as argument, as you're not using the shell to execute the program:

```
cmd = ['/usr/bin/passwd', '--stdin', sys_user]
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

then you need to call the communicate method on the `proc` object to get the stdin/stdout:

```
out, err = proc.communicate(password)
for l in out.split('\n'):
    print out
```

and there you go!

N.B.: to get the passwd from standard input using python, have a look at the [`getpass`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/getpass.html) module.

Comment: Where does the passwd argument to proc.communicate come from?

Comment: from the same place the OP's is taking it.

Comment: OK I got it thanks and for a list it can be any number of arguements

Comment: basically, it's the string you want to give to `stdin` of the `passwd` command. Which you can get by using `getpass.getpass()`.